# Word 2010 Headings use of heading out of order 1,3,2

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, headers

Can a non sequential header be used without advancing the number order of the next heading order?  Example: Header sequencing with Multilevel list linked to style headers:
Header 1 starts with 1).

When Header 3 is used after Header 1 numbering starts with i).

When Header 2 is then used it starts with "b" not "a".

Is their code, I need to some how delete?

Or is the best way just not to use Header 3 after Header 1?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the numbering for the Heading2, and then click **Restart at a**.